# Nullpointer exception while transfering a value from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

my project concept is depend upon the dropdown value the control will be tranfer to the related jsp page.

i created 4 dropdown value

1.andriod

2.struts

3.spring

4.hibernate

And 4 jsp page

1.andriod.jsp

2.struts.jsp

3.spring.jsp

4.hibernate.jsp

if i selected andriod and click the submit button mean the control will be transfer to andriod.jsp page,similarly other value also transfered,

My Problem is

If i selected andriod  and click the submit button it always shows null pointer exception...

Please any one solve my problem.

i created

1.jsp page(Filename.jsp)

2.Servlet page(CatServ.java)

**NewFile.jsp**

```
<body>
<form action="test" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Select the category</td>
<td>
<select>
  <option name="andriod"       value="lang">Andriod</option>
  <option name="java"           value="lang">Java</option>
  <option name="struts"         value="lang">Struts</option>
  <option name="spring"        value="lang">Spring</option>
  <option name="hybernate"   value="lang">Hybernate</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

**CatServ.java**

```
package container;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CatServ
 */
@WebServlet("/CatServ")
public class CatServ extends HttpServlet
 {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s=request.getParameter("lang");
        System.out.println(s);

        if(s.equals("andriod"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("AndriodServ.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(s.equals("java"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("JavaServ.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(s.equals("struts"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("StrutsServ.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(s.equals("spring"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("SpringServ.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(s.equals("hibernate"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Hybernate.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i post my html code but i will be disable,please any one enable my html code,i don't know how to enable it...

Comment: Put your code in code blocks (the button with the curly braces).  Also, don't forget to properly format your code, too.

Comment: Read, then give us the full stack trace of the exception. It tells you exactly at which line in which file the error happens. Errors are not just red flags. They come with meaningful error messages intended to be read by the developer (YOU).

Comment: what do you get from System.out.println(s); in your servlet ? does it say null ? if so check Ryan snwer below

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing name and value. You need `<select name="lang">` and your options should be like `<option value="spring">`.

Answer (score 1):

To work it correctly you have to re write your select like bellow

```
<select name="lang">
 <option  value="andriod">Andriod</option>
<option  value="java">Java</option>
<option  value="struts">Struts</option>
<option  value="spring">Spring</option>
<option  value="hybernate">Hybernate</option>
</select>
```

You could check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_name.asp) for more info

Also note it is good practice to check `s` for null before call `equals`

```
if(s !=null) {
// do my checks
}
```

Comment: If you reverse the order (that is, `"android".equals(s)`), then you won't need to check for null; if `s` truly is null, then the equals will evaluate to false.